# Flutter using a stream within another stream

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, stream

I have a flutter project that uses firebase as a database. I am trying to get a list of document names via a stream, break it into sets of 10 to workaround the 10 comparison maximum for the .where() function in firebase then make batch requests using .where() and merge them.

The problems that I am aware of are:

1. friends.length cannot be used as a number in a loop because it is of type future
2. The  firestore query return cannot be added to the stream list for reasons I do not understand ("The argument type 'Query' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Stream'.")
3. .where() is expecting 1 positional argument but I am giving it 3, though this is what the firestore documentation says I should do
4. StreamGroup is underfined

```
  Stream<List<Memo>> get memos {
    // create list of streams
    List<Stream> streams = [];
    // Get list of friend userids
    var friends = Firestore.instance.collection("users").document(userid).collection("friends").snapshots().map(_snapshotToStringList);
    // split friend userid list into chunks of 10
    for (var i = 0; i < friends.length; i += 10) {
      // query database for each chunk of 10 and add to stream list
      streams.add(Firestore.instance.collection("memos").where("userid", "in", friends.sublist(i, i+10)));
    }
    // merge and return stream list
    return StreamGroup.merge(streams);
  }
```

Any and all advice is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code:

```
Stream<List<Memo>> get memos {
  List<Stream> streams = [];
  Firestore.instance
      .collection("users")
      .document(userid)
      .collection("friends")
      .snapshots()
      .map(_snapshotToStringList)
      .listen((friends){
    for (var i = 0; i < friends.length; i += 10) {
    // query database for each chunk of 10 and add to stream list
      streams.add(Firestore.instance
        .collection("memos")
        .where("userid", isEqualTo: friends.sublist(i, i+10)));
    }
  });
  return StreamGroup.merge(streams);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this looks a whole lot better than what I had, it appears that there is still an issue however. The expression within streams.add still is erronous as an argument type 'Query' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Stream<dynamic>'. I would also like to ask if there is an import necessary to use StreamGroup as it is undefined.

Comment: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/package-async_async/StreamGroup-class.html
its async class but i cannot use StreamGroup too its undefined even if i import async class idont know it maybe removed

Comment: The streamgroup issue was resolved by importing the package https://pub.dev/packages/async. The streams.add issue I raised above can be resolved by converting the list to type Query that cannot be merged with StreaGroup. Do you have any suggestions? I apologize for all these questions, I am very new to flutter and firebase.

Comment: streams.add(Firestore.instance.collection("memos").where("userid", isEqualTo: friends.sublist(i, i+10)).snapshots());
use this for adding stream